# PHP - Curl is unable to get local issuer certificate for only one domain

Tags: php, ssl, curl

When trying to access one particular API through curl in PHP, I get the curl error code 60 - unable to get local issuer certificate. The strange thing is that I only get this error for this particular domain, and only when using curl in php.

When accessing the API with command line curl, the issue does not occur. When trying to access any other SSL domain via curl in php, the issue does not occur. In fact, I have found another website that uses the same intermediate certificate (i.e. RapidSSL Global TLS RSA4096 SHA256 2022 CA1), and *I can access that website*.

I have of course tried setting cacert.pem manually, for both curl and openssl, through both the php.ini and through `curl_setopt` in code, but to no avail. I have also verified that the root certificate that is used by the problematic api (i.e. Digicert Global Root CA) is present in both the downloaded and default CA stores.

At this point, I would appreciate any guesses as to what could possibly be causing this behaviour.

Here is the output of Curl in verbose mode when trying to access the problematic website:

```
*   Trying <IP>:443...
* Connected to <Domain> (<IP>) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
*  CAfile: /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
```

Update: after running [testssl.sh](https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh), it seems that chain of trust is not entirely complete. This does not explain why only curl *with php* has this issue, and I would still appreciate it if anybody could point me to a way to accept this particular flaw without disabling SSL verification entirely.

Comment: how up to date is `cert.pem`?

Comment: Hard to tell without having anything to reproduce, i.e. the name of the domain and ideally also the CA file used. If you don't want to provide these information check the site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look out for chain issues which might be restricted to only IPv4 vs IPv6 or RSA vs. ECDSA certificates.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius cert.pem was downloaded from Mozilla today, should be very recent.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Unfortunately the API is behind a company firewall, so SSLLabs is going to be difficult. However, I do have a script lying around that does similar checks from the local machine, so I'll give that a try.